# What to do if FUSE has no option NOFAIL in Raspian Bullseye 64bit?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, 64-bit, fuses

When I use `nofail` in `fstab` with `mp3fs` (which is a filesystem that mounts `flac` and others as `mp3` on-the-fly), I get the error

`fuse: unknown option 'nofail'`

My `fstab`:

`mp3fs#/mnt/mybook /mnt/mp3fs fuse nofail,noauto,allow_other,ro,bitrate=192,x-systemd.requires-mounts-for=/mnt/mybook 0 0`

I was under the (false) impression that this already worked in Buster. Am I mistaken or did I lose the ability to use nofail by upgrading from 32bit Debian Buster to 64bit Bullseye (on a Raspberry Pi)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read about this issue here: https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/issues/691

So there seems to be `libfuse 2.9.9` in Debian Bullseye: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/fuse

The entry for Buster looks similar, except there is an extra mentioning of `fuse3`: https://packages.debian.org/buster/fuse

So I `apt install fuse3` and the option `nofail` is recognised properly. No boot hang when the mount does not work!

Awesome!

However I got the message

```
dpkg: fuse: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 ntfs-3g depends on fuse.
 exfat-fuse depends on fuse.
```

Hopefully, `fuse3` will work with them like `fuse`.